# What are valid Azure ML Workspace connection argument options?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azure-python-sdk

I want to build an Azure ML environment with two python packages that I have in Azure Devops.
For this I need a workspace connection to Azure Devops. One package is published to an artifact feed and I can access it using the python SDK using a personal access token:

```
ws.set_connection(name="ConnectionName", 
                  category= "PythonFeed", 
                  target = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/", 
                  authType = "PAT", 
                  value = PAT_TOKEN)
```

However, for the other I need to get the package from the git repository in Azure Devops. The documentation of the [Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.workspace.workspace?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-workspace-workspace-set-connection) and the underlying [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/workspace-connections/create) don't give the options for the arguments, only that they need to be strings (see links).

My question: what are the options for the following arguments:

- authType
- category
- valueFormat

And what do I need to set for target argument, so that I can connect to the Azure DevOps repository with potentially different authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the package from a Azure DevOps git repository you can change the target to the repository URL:

```
ws.set_connection(
    name="ConnectionName", 
    category = "PythonFeed",
    target = "https://dev.azure.com/<MY-ORG>/<MY-PROJECT>/_git/<MY-REPO>", 
    authType = "PAT", 
    value = <PAT-TOKEN>)
```

Note here that there is no user specified in the URL (the standard "clone" URL in Azure DevOps also contains "DevOps-Vx@").

As for any other options for "authType", "category" and "valueFormat", I don't know.